# Select list option (onchange) in web form using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to change the Case Reopen list option to "Yes". Here my code changing the option, but not triggered well.

**Example:** if changed **Case Reopen** to "yes" then I can able change **TAT Start Date**

Please see below images and code for better understanding my issue

**option: No**:

[image]

**option: Yes**

[image]

**VBA Code**

```
ie.document.getElementsByName("cf_1314")(0).selectedIndex = "1"

  ie.document.getElementsByName("cf_1314")(0).FireEvent ("onchange")
```

**html Code:**

[image]

Comment: Can you share the URL? More of the HTML? Also, use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert code i.e. not as an image as we can't copy paste that for testing.

Comment: I can't share URL it's internal CRM tool

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the getElementsByTagName with option tag? Something like

```
Set TDelements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("option")

For Each TDelement In TDelements
  If TDelement.Value = "No" Then
     TDelement.Value = "Yes"  
  End if
Next
```